# Is it possible to hardcode Kentico webparts into a layout?

Tags: kentico

Kentico 8.2.

I've got a layout "master" file - the creatively named Master.ascx.

I've got three web part zones in the layout: header, main and footer. Main just includes a content placeholder which is overridden by the next layout down - home, standard, whatever.

I *could* just drag and drop web parts onto the header and footer web part zones on to the "design" tab, but I don't want to for a few reasons:

1. Which web parts go in which zone is stored in the database, which isn't versioned in Git. The layout file itself *is* versioned via the "store CMS Virtual Files on disk" option.
2. The layout markup inside the header is complicated enough that I'll end up needing to have 4 or 5 web part zones for 4 or 5 web parts - or I'll need to write a layout web part or drag row layouts / column layouts in, etc - it seems much simpler to just hardcode web parts inside bespoke markup.
3. I find editing a plain text file with Visual Studio much faster than dragging and dropping web parts into a zone, and the same applies for anyone else who'll ever work on this site.
4. Which web parts go in which web part zone doesn't ever change - there's always a primary nav, share-on-facebook, etc - which web parts are included will never need to be in any way dynamic.

Is it possible to just hardcode a web part into my layout?

Comment: In this case maybe [ASPX templates](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Choosing+the+right+development+model) development model is better for you.

Comment: It is an option but I'd really weigh the benefits of ASPX over Portal or even Portal and ASPX.  Straight ASPX is never an option when I create Kentico sites.  Understanding how Kentico works and how to develop against it, is really key.  Typically when I come into an upgrade situation and have to deal with a straight ASPX site, the work job nearly triples in size because of the custom code you have to sift through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, no you cannot hard code webparts in your layout.  Simple reasoning is webparts are not part of a layout, they are part of a template .  The webpart definition for each template is stored with the template in the database as XML.  You can see this by going to a template and selecting the Webparts tab and it will display all the XML for each of the webparts on that page template.

Understand where you're coming from with your 4 points.  What you also need to consider is:

- what happens when you want/need upgrade or apply a hotfix?
- from the client, content editor and content administrators perspective, having everything in code, renders the CMS pretty useless.
- if you code everything in a physical file, it's then pretty pointless to have a CMS if it requires a developer or a physical code change for every request

The point of the CMS is to be dynamic and database driven.  Not everything can reside in the file system, database or a code repository.  Kentico has some very strong developer tools you can enable like workflow, versioning, and check-in/out.

I'd also enable your DBA and ensure they have a valid backup and recovery plan in the event of some disaster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, suspected it wasn't possible but I wanted to make sure.

Sorry to be disagreeable, but the client is paying us to design and develop their templates for them and they're neither design nor tech savvy enough to be moving web parts around in these zones - I'm using editor zones for all of the "content" parts of the page and hoping that they'll never need to use the "design" tab.

Appreciate that Kentico has some built in versioning for the templates, but it's not as good as Git.

For now I'm just manually copying that XML "web parts" tab to a file in Git.

Comment: No reason to be sorry, I'm always up for a challenge and helping others learn more about Kentico.  

So in the event of the non-tech savvy client I typically use page types and widgets.  Sounds as if you're already using widgets.  You might also look into page types.  I build my sites so clients only touch the Edit and Form tabs, that's it.  Agree, Kentico does have some versioning for almost everything but not at good as GIT, remember Kentico is a CMS not a code repo... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because it goes against the Portal Engine development model. If your main issue is the unavailability of these objects in GIT consider the option to save virtual objects (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Deployment+mode+for+virtual+objects) to the file system, so they are picked up by GIT. I'd also suggest to keep the website upgrade safe (e.g. by using the Portal model), because the next version will feature CI support (saving of all DB objects to the file system) http://www.kentico.com/product/roadmap which is due to be released in 2 months

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, please review [answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wanted to, but I need a reputation of 50 to add comments